# Let $X$ be the random variable having probability density, find the CDF...

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be the random variable having probability density

$f (x) =x$ if $0 <x <1$, $1/2$ if $1 ≤ x <2$ and $0$ otherwise
+
I have to find the distribution function $F (x) = P (X ≤ x)$.

I did this:

$F(x)=0$ if $x<0$

$F(x)=\int_0^x(t)dt=x^2/2$ if $0 ≤ x <1$

$F(x)=x^2/2+\int_1^x(1/2)t=(x^2+x-1)/2$ if $1≤x<2$

$F(x)=1$ if $x>=2$

Why is this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For $1\le x<2$, it is $$\int_0^1 x dx + \int_1^x \frac{1}{2}dx = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{x-1}{2}$$